# Excel VBA: How will I make my Loop function properly?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

**Short:**

I have a workbook that has checkboxes and a pivottable.
Upon refreshing, the data stored will be transferred to another sheet.
Additionally, when the checkbox is checked it will get a status "True" and will also be updated.

Upon refreshing the pivottable the "article" is then cleared from the Pivot table.

**Problem:**

<strike>When I set the 1st checkbox to "True" the next article in the sequence will be somehow skipped.</strike>

All the others will be fine.

When I set the 1st and 3rd and 6th, it will skip an equal number of lines,
so 2 will be skipped. 4 and 5 and 7,8,9

**Expected result:**

<strike>I don't want the lines to be skipped.</strike>

If checkbox true then update the status to true then refresh pt.
go to next article.

I don't need the checkbox false result.

Thoughts:

<strike>I guess my loop is somehow not looping properly because I set some code outside of its boundaries.
I don't know where exactly.</strike>

**Additional:**

I'm relatively new to VBA and haven't learned yet how to generate clean code.
Yes, I created an odd checkbox variable.

**Update:**
I figured out that this part makes everything go ape.
there is no need to refresh after every cycle
Yes, there needs to be a refresh at the end of the complete cycle.

> 

```
'Set active checkbox to false
If Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value = True Then
Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value = False
'Refresh Pivot table
Blad4.PivotTables("PT_EXCESS").PivotCache.Refresh
End If
```

**If someone would be kind to help me figure out**

I cannot quite figure out how to exit my loop.
Yes, i can "do until". and "exit for".

But i don't know what code needs to be replaced because,
For each article in rng. makes the whole code work :( .

```
Sub status()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim LookupValue As String
    Dim Article As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Blad4.Range("A4:A13")
  
    For Each Article In rng
    LookupValue = Article

    Set tbl = Blad2.ListObjects("PQ_ABC_EXCESS")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FoundCell = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    
    FoundCell.Offset(, 16).Value = Article.Offset(, 4)

    cbnr = Article.Row - 3
    cb = "Checkbox" & cbnr

    Else
    MsgBox "Value not found"
    End If
    
    If Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value = True Then
    FoundCell.Offset(, 17).Value = Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value
    Else
    End If

    'Set active checkbox to false
    If Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value = True Then
    Blad4.OLEObjects(cb).Object.Value = False
    'Refresh Pivot table
    Blad4.PivotTables("PT_EXCESS").PivotCache.Refresh
    End If

    Next Article

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you are specifically guaranteeing that the checkbox names have numbers that will always be three minus the row number, you'd do better by looking at the checkbox cell to determine its address and matching the row number from that. Look at `OLEObjects(x).TopLeftCell.Address`

Comment: Hi peter,
thanks for your advice I will look into that.
I like more elegant solutions like yours :)
(I am certain that these checkboxes will forever remain the same numbers)

Comment: @desotronics Don't fix your problem in the question, that's not how Stack Overflow works. Post an answer to present your fix instead.